# $\int a^x/(1+a^{2x})dx$ by substitution or another method?

Tags: integration

I need to calculate $$\int \frac{a^x}{(1+a^{2x})}dx$$ Any tips? I tried putting $a^x=t$,  dividing and placing $a^x$ into differential, but without success. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: try multiplying the fraction by $ \frac {lna}{lna}$

Comment: Your substitution seems correct. Please show the steps you took so that we can assess where you might have made a mistake or where you didn't see what the next step should be.

Comment: I see that I made mistake while substituting $a^x=t$. Now it's all trivial. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=a^x$.

Then $$x=\frac{\ln(t)}{\ln(a)} \implies \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{t\ln(a)} \iff dx=\frac{1}{\ln(a)}\cdot \frac{1}{t}d t.$$

Then we have $$\require{cancel}\frac{1}{\ln(a)}\int \frac{\cancel t}{1+t^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\cancel t}dt=\frac{1}{\ln(a)} \int \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt \ .$$

Now use the fact that $$\int \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\arctan(t)+C .$$

Answer (score 1):

On substituting $t=a^x$, we have $dt=a^x\ln a\,dx=t\ln a\,dx$. Hence

$\begin{align}\int \frac{a^x}{(1+a^{2x})}\,dx&=\int \frac{t}{(1+t^2)t\ln a}\,dt
\\&=\frac{1}{\ln a}\int\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt
\\&=\frac{\arctan t}{\ln a}+C
\\&=\frac{\arctan a^x}{\ln a}+C
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

if 
$$
t=a^x 
$$
then
$$
\log t = x \log a \\
dx = \frac{dt}{t \log a}
$$
hence
$$
I = \int \frac{dt}{1+t^2}
$$